# Huge area of stuck pixels

Tags: display, stuck-pixel

A toddler slammed down my laptop screen while an iPod was laying on top of the keyboard.

The damage resulted in a massive area of stuck pixels on the laptop screen, approximately 2 inches by 10 inches in area.

I've tried running various programs that rapidly flick the pixels in different colors, as well as massaging the screen with heat and also without heat. These are the standard methods I read about for fixing a stuck pixel. But none of the online articles I read said how to fix a huge area of pixels, not just single pixels.

What else can I try to get the many pixels unstuck? My computer is no longer under warranty and I don't want to buy a new one.

Comment: This sounds a lot like screen damage, not stuck pixels (they're slightly different). When you have large swaths of bad pixels like that, it's usually because the LCD was cracked, as opposed to a single pixel which is functional, but having some difficulty turning on or off. If you aren't up to replacing it yourself, using an external monitor might be the cheapest route.

Comment: I'll also add that you can probably pay to have the screen replaced. If you go to the right shop, they can give you some kind of good deal on buying a perhaps after-market replacement screen that's cheaper than the vendor part. Depending on how high-end and current your laptop is, it could be economical to do so.

Comment: @DarthAndroid put that as an answer... I was just about to before I saw you already wrote it.

Comment: You should see if there is a youtube video of someone replacing a screen on that model.  My kid cracked the screen on his net book, and I was able to get the part off Amazon,,and fix it.  But I wouldn't have wanted to do it without the disassembly instructions ("press here until you hear a pop" etc)  video because it always seems to be more than just find the screws and use a screwdriver

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to replace the LCD display but it may be cheaper and easier than you think.  http://www.screencountry.com/ is a vendor for every kind of replacement LCD and they provide video tutorials on installation.  It may not be something a beginner should attempt but any computer tech should be able to handle it.

I replaced a 15" Dell laptop display for under $200 - including paying a tech to do the installation.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like screen damage, not stuck pixels (they're slightly different). When you have large swaths of bad pixels like that, it's usually because the LCD was cracked, as opposed to a single pixel which is functional, but having some difficulty turning on or off. If you aren't up to replacing it yourself, using an external monitor might be the cheapest route.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the heat solution, although you need your CPU temperature to be under 95 F.

1. Use a towel 10x10 cm, heat up the towel to at least 140 F.
2. Leave the screen open, as you try to rub the screen (the heat may burn your hands to death, so use silicone gloves)on the stuck pixels(and the heat may burn the glass, so be careful and not put too much pressure).
3. If you can't work all stuck pixels (or none) you will have to repeat again, but this time, increase the temperature by 9 F until it works, but you have to take 5 minutes for a cool down.